# Best practice: Versioning and releases in multiprojects

Tags: java, maven, dependencies, release, continuum

What is the best practice for versioning and release management in the following case with multiprojects?

### Project structure

- global parent

  - parent project (Version: 1.0-SNAPSHOT)

    - child project 1 (same like parent)
    - child project 2 (same like parent)
    - child project 3 (same like parent)
    - child project 4 (same like parent)
    - …

I want to set only one time the version for the parent and all child projects, because every part of the project must have the same version.

Also what i want is, to release the project with continuum/maven.

### Current "bad" solution:

Normaly a easy way should be to set the version in the parent pom and say in every child „last version from parent“ but this dont work with maven <3.1 (See here)[http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/MNG-624]
Now i set in every child project the version of the parent project and for every release i must change the version in all childs and the parent.

Example:

**Parent**

```
<groupId>com.test</groupId>
<artifactId>com.test.buildDefinition</artifactId>
<version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
```

**Child**

```
<parent>
    <groupId>com.test</groupId>
    <artifactId>com.test.buildDefinition</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
</parent>

<groupId>com.test</groupId>
<artifactId>com.test.project</artifactId>
<version>${parent.version}</version>
```

If i want to release my projects now with Continuum i use the following order to release it:

1. Parent Project
2. Child Project 1
3. Child Project 2
4. …

But this dont work, because after changeing the version of the parent, the childs dont have anymore a SNAPSHOT version in the parent and i think there must be a better way to release a multiproject with continuum.

Comment: Is it a multi-module project ?

Comment: No currently i dont work with multi-module. But i think to have a look on it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you add your child modules in the `<dependencyManagement/>` tag I am quite sure that you will not have that problem.

**Parent**

```
<groupId>com.test</groupId>
<artifactId>com.test.buildDefinition</artifactId>
<version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>pom</packaging>

<modules>
    <module>child1</module>
    <module>child2</module>
</modules>

<dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.test</groupId>
            <artifactId>com.test.child1</artifactId>
            <version>${project.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.test</groupId>
            <artifactId>com.test.child2</artifactId>
            <version>${project.version}</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>
```

**Child1**

```
<parent>
    <groupId>com.test</groupId>
    <artifactId>com.test.buildDefinition</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
</parent>

<!-- groupId and version can be skipped since it will be inherited from parent -->
<artifactId>com.test.child1</artifactId>
```

**Child2 (depends on Child1)**

```
<parent>
    <groupId>com.test</groupId>
    <artifactId>com.test.buildDefinition</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
</parent>

<!-- groupId and version can be skipped since it will be inherited from parent -->
<artifactId>com.test.child2</artifactId>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.test</groupId>
        <artifactId>com.test.child1</artifactId>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

If you try to when using the dependencyManagement the dependencies between modules will never have to define any versions since they are defined in the parents pom.

I have never had any problems with releasing multi-module projects by this approach.

**Edit**

To be clear: `dependencyManagement` does not have anything to do with the inheritence between parent-child. It solves any problems with the version of dependencies between child modules. And it works during releases.

Answer (score 1):

You should create a multi-module structure, under a single version control hierarchy, for the simultaneously, identically versioned modules. Continuum will allow you to add them to a group either as a single job or multiple jobs per module, and either way the release mechanism will trigger from the parent and automatically resolve the versions for you.

Incidentally, you can drop `<version>${parent.version}</version>` and the identical groupId, as they will be inherited from the parent.

If the global parent is released separately, you should split that out into a separate module rather than making it part of the same multi-module structure. You can find an example project in this layout here: https://github.com/brettporter/centrepoint

Answer (score 0):

If you want all the version numbers to stay in sync, you can make use of the [autoVersionSubmodules](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-release-plugin/prepare-mojo.html#autoVersionSubmodules) flag of the Maven release plugin. Setting this value to true will allow you to perform a release at the top project level and have all the sub-modules released with the same version as the parent.

This can be specified on the command line when you run `mvn -DautoVersionSubmodules release:prepare` or in a POM file as follows:

```xml
<plugin>
  <artifactId>maven-release-plugin</artifactId>        
  <version>2.3.2</version>
  <configuration>
    <autoVersionSubmodules>true</autoVersionSubmodules>
  </configuration>
</plugin>
```

I haven't used Continuum, but I believe it uses the Maven release plugin under the covers? Some Googling suggests this might work (based on a number of "nice to have" bugs regarding how the Continuum interface handles this scenario).

Comment: that's correct, Continuum's release feature uses the Maven release plugin, including honouring the flag you've mentioned.